# Explain the difference between the following 2 sentences

Tags: descriptive-grammar

They always eat in front of the TV in the living room.
They're always eating in front of the TV in the living room.

Comment: What is it that you do not understand?

Answer (score 1):

> They always eat in front of the TV in the living room.

This answers the question, "Where do they usually eat dinner?" Instead of eating dinner at a dinner table in the dining room, they sit on the sofa and eat in front of the TV in the living room. Perhaps, these people go to work all day. When they come home, they make dinner and eat while watching TV.

> They're always eating in front of the TV in the living room.

This answers the question, "How do they usually spend their time?" Instead of living a healthy and active life, they sit in front of the TV and eat all day. Perhaps, these people are lazy and overweight.

Answer (score 1):

In the sentence with the Present Continuous Tense we don't give the real information about the frequency of 'eating in front  of the TV', but we exaggerate the information (as if the only thing they always do is 'eating in front of the TV').

There's a good answer on *https://www.englishpage.com › verbpage*:

"The present continuous with words such as "always" or "constantly" expresses the idea that something irritating or shocking often happens. Notice that the meaning is like simple present, but with negative emotion."